# Configure Pyscripter to Manage different python distributions (Anaconda and ArcGIS)

Tags: python, anaconda, arcpy, pyscripter

I'm in trouble working with Pyscripter. I have ArcGIS (Geographical Information System software) that install python 2.7.5 by default. I'm trying to work in Pyscripter with Anaconda and arcpy (the ArcGIS python package), but the Pyscripter only "see" ArcGIS python distribution (in C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2). My Anaconda installation folder was C:\Python27\Anaconda.

I can import arcpy into pyscripter, but not pandas or scipy, for example. When I type

```
import sys
sys.version
```

I see:

'2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]'

When type python in cmd and repeat the sys.version I see:

'2.7.5 | Anaconda 1.6.0 (32-bit) | (default, May 31 2013, 10:43:53) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (intel)]'

So I realize that is pyscripter that doesn't "see" anaconda packages.

Any idea of how to manage with this?

Comment: Please check these two posts for an answer.  If they work, please add an answer to this Q on how they helped.
https://pymorton.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/using-arcpy-with-anaconda/
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86850/how-to-make-a-separate-python-installation-that-can-call-arcgis-arcpy

Answer (score 1):

The version of modules and python in default Anaconda is likely newer than what is available w/in the ESRI python stack (most notably numpy). Therefore, you'll need to figure what versions of pandas, scipy, whatever else you want work with the numpy you get in ESRI python first. Then you use `conda` to create a custom environment w/in Anaconda that has the libraries you want, but that match the ESRI python you have installed. Then you let ESRI python know about the custom environment. Then you are good to go.

The following is for ArcGIS 10.2.2.

In ArcMap's python, type:

```
import sys, numpy, matplotlib
print(sys.version, numpy.__version__, matplotlib.__version__)
```

you might get something like:

```
'2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]', '1.7.1', '1.3.0')
```

Get to the Anaconda Command Prompt (`Start > Search > Anaconda, pick "Anaconda Command Prompt` on Windows) and type:

```
conda create -n arc1022 python=2.7.5 numpy=1.7.1 matplotlib=1.3.0
```

to create a new virtual environment, `arc1022`.

Tell ArcGIS about this stuff by including a file, `arc1022.pth`, in `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages` (path may vary per your install path for Arc). The contents of this file should include:

```
C:\Anaconda\envs\arc1022\Lib\site-packages
```

(this path may vary slightly depending on where you've installed Anaconda).